# memory leaks with NSAttributedStrings

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsattributedstring

My app is book-like with 77 chapters each comprised of several pages. On each page, text is displayed in a `UITextView`. The data for this is stored in a dictionary of type `[String: [NSAttrubutedString]]`. The keys are chapters, the array elements associated with each chapter are the strings for each page in that chapter.

Instruments shows in the vicinity of 1800 memory leaks when the app first boots. I sometimes see 1 to 17 more leaks upon accessing other pages but this is rare and unpredictable. The 1800 varies and only appears once. I had no such issues when using non-attributed `String`s. I might also add this is my first experience with attributed strings.

One example each of some leaks (sizes are total for that type):
    * Malloc / [NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] / 171 kB
    * Malloc 80 Bytes / -[NSRLEArray_makeNewListFrom:] 17 kB
    * _NSCFString / -[NSPlaceholderMutableString init]  23 kB
    * Malloc / [NSMutableRLEArray_setBlockCapacity:] / 25 kB
    * NSConcreteMutableAttributedString / _decodeObjectBinary 12 kB

Although I use the mutable version to form my strings I insert them into the arrays as the non-mutable `NSAttributedString` version. The dictionary of arrays is archived as a `plist` then read into dictionary of the same type when the app is booted. I thought this might be the issue but attempts to read directly from the archive produced the same leaks. I don't know why the leaked objects read as mutable.

I'm not sure what code, if any, would be helpful here, let me know.

Edit: I've replaced the dictionary with an array, `[[NSAttributedString]]` but still have the same issue. At least three of the leaked categories seem related to the same strings, the number of leaks in each is about the same.

Edit: I've eliminated my leaks by creating the dictionary live on `viewDidLoad` as opposed to reading it from an archive. But I'm still curious why this behavior with attributed strings versus strings.

Comment: same here.. i too am getting memory leaks when i use NSMutableAttributedString in my project..I hv no ideas why this issue is occuring?

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: refer: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9493